# Para proyecto escolar me están pidiendo un login en React conectado a una API en PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, react-native

Esto es lo que hecho en React pero no encuentro como generar una alerta o mensaje que me indique que el inicio es correcto o mensaje de error si algun dato es incorrecto.

Esto es lo que llevo de codigo:

```
 ingresar(){
        if(this.state.email !== '' && this.state.password !==''){
            // alert('Inicio Correcto')
            fetch('http://localhost/servicios/index.php/API/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body:'&Email='+this.state.email + '&Password='+this.state.password
            })
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                if(result.succes){
                    console.log('inicio correcto')
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error){

            });
        }else{
            alert('falta llenar campos');
        }
    }
```

Comment: el mensaje de si es correcto o no el inicio de sesión, deberá salir de CI y tomarlo con React a través de una petición AJAX para entonces mostrarlo en pantalla

Comment: Mmm... aun no he llegado a esa parte de AJAX en la facultad...

Comment: de hecho acorde a tu código si, es la petición `fetch` que muestras, de ella obtienes una respuesta de la petición que haces a la URL del servidor, lo que te falta es procesar lo que se retorna de validar el usuario y la contraseña

Comment: @ArturoCastilloZapata lo que podrias hacer es que en la respuesta de la peticion(si esta es satisfactoria) modifique un estado antes predefinido en false.

Answer (score 0):

Importa la el componente `Alert` de la librería `react-native` donde mismo importas `View` o `Text` y después úsalo con el comando `Alert.alert('Aquí va mi mensaje de alerta');`

Se quedaría algo así:

```
import { View, Alert (... los demás componentes que tengas) } from 'react-native'

...

(En tu código donde haces el console.log del success)

Alert.alert('Aquí va mi mensaje de alerta');
```